# How do you horizontally align text from two different tags

Tags: css

How do you align text from two different tags? Code is shown below with the result.

```
<input-layout label="TEST_TITLE">
        <div>
          <p class="no-gap">TEST_TEXT1</p>
          <p class="no-gap"><small style="color:red; font-size: 10px;">TEST_TEXT2</small></p>
        </div>
</input-layout>
```

[image]

My goal is to align `TEST_TITLE` with `TEST_TEXT1` while the small red text `TEST_TEXT2` remains directly below `TEST_TEXT1` like the way it is now.

I thought about adding an `inline-block` to the `div` but that didn't do anything. I'm terrible with CSS so your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of flex to align your headings here.

Created a short example for you, please check :

```
 <div id="box" style=" display: flex; flex-direction: row">
    <div style="background: yellow; display: flex;" id="left">
      <p class="no-gap">TEST_TITLE</p>
    </div>
    <div  id="right" style=" display: flex; flex-direction: column; ">
      <div style="background: cyan">
          <p class="no-gap">TEST_TEXT1</p>
      </div>
      <div style="background: aqua">
          <p class="no-gap"><small style="color:red; font-size: 10px;">TEST_TEXT2</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/tzMZLG6JsFkwJLTy?open=lib%2Fscript.js

You can refer the documentation here: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/